# I want count of processes in variable & if the count is less than particular number then it will generate email

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting

I want count of processes in one file & if the count is less than particular number then it will generate one mail.

Here is my code:

```
--@echo off
cd /
:start
tasklist |find "svchost.exe" >process.txt
SET /P V1=| findstr /R /N "^" process.txt|find /C":"

IF "%V1%"=="12" (GOTO :start ) ELSE 
(Send-MailMessage -to "sender_id" -from "PowerShell <receipient_id>" -Subject "Test" -body "Test for Send-MailMessage")

pause
```

Comment: You have added the powershell tag. Do you want this as a batch script (what your code currently is)? Or do you actually want it in powershell?

Comment: What problem are you having specifically?  Is the code not giving  you the desired output?  What is it doing exactly.  Your code also looks incomplete.  Maybe if you posted the whole file?

Comment: I tried above code, but its not giving me desired o/p..iF count of process are =12 then it'll agin jump to :start(simply will go into loop & will check again & again).. else it'll trigger the mail..

Comment: So, do you want batch or powershell for the solution? Which one? Powershell is simpler in my opinion.

Comment: anything would be great if you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
if((get-process 'svchost').Count -lt 12)
{
    Send-MailMessage -to "sender_id" -from "PowerShell <receipient_id>" -Subject "Test" -body "Test for Send-MailMessage" -SMTPServer 'mail.something.com'
}
```

Comment: Actually you will need to add the SMTP server parameter to the Send-MailMessage cmdlet. I will add a placeholder in the answer but I don't know your server details of course.

Comment: Thanks for the info but, Now i have below code for inplementation  

cd \
:start
for /f %%i in ('tasklist^|find /c "svchost.exe"') do set /a count=%%i
if %count% geq 12 goto :start

telnet smtp.domain.com 25
helo domain.com
mail from: <Sender@domain.com>
rcpt to: <recpnt@domain.com>
DATA
SUBJECT:Test

This Is The Test Mail.
.
quit

pause


while executing batch code is getting stuck on telnet step(else clause).
from  "helo to quit" asking for manual input.

Comment: So did you try the code that I posted. It will send the email if there are less than 12 Svchost processes.

Comment: cd \
:start
for /f %%i in ('tasklist^|find /c "svchost.exe"') do set /a count=%%i
if %count% geq 12 goto :start

telnet smtp.domain.com 25
helo domain.com
mail from: <Sender@domain.com>
rcpt to: <recpnt@domain.com>
DATA
SUBJECT:Test

This Is The Test Mail.
.
quit

pause

Comment: What is not working about the code that I posted? Do you get an error?

Comment: Yes, not recognized internal or external command at send-MailMessage

Comment: That means you are running it in a command prompt not a Powershell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

most of the `cmd` commands are more powerful than you seem to think:

```
:start
timeout 1     :: wait cycle to reduce cpu workload
for /f %%i in ('tasklist^|find /c "svchost.exe"') do set /a count=%%i
if %count% geq 12 goto :start
echo count is less than 12
```